# ListView.ItemsPanel is not created

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl named 'GridPage' that contains ListView with Grid as ItemsPanel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StoreManager.VirtuePrint.GridPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="300" d:DesignHeight="300" Width="21cm" Height="29.7cm">
    <ListView Name="listView" Width="21cm" Height="29.7cm">
        <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" IsItemsHost="True" Background="White"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding InnerView.Entity.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

it works fine if I create it as normal control inside some Window, but when I try to print it using DocumentPaginator with the following code:

```
class GridPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    ....


    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        GridPage grid = new GridPage()
        {
            Width = pageLayout.PaperSizeInPixels.Width,

            Height = pageLayout.PaperSizeInPixels.Height
        };

        ...

        grid.Measure(pageLayout.PaperSizeInPixels);

        grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), pageLayout.PaperSizeInPixels));

        //finally return the page

        return new DocumentPage(grid);
    }

    ...
}
```

Grid's Loaded event does not fire and ListView.ItemsPanel is not created (((System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl)(listView))._itemsHost is null). ListView exists (not null) but it does not have ItemsPanel in this case.

What can cause this situation?

Comment: You might try to also call `grid.InvalidateVisual()` after `grid.Arrange()`.

Comment: I tried grid.InvalidateVisual() but it does not help.